# loading a nib depending on user cell input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nib

hello i am wondering how its possible to load a nib depending on the string selected from the cell title. 
here is the code that i am using however i cant get any results..

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 //FinalViewController *anotherViewController = [[FinalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalViewController" bundle:nil];

 if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath].textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Ath 1"])
 {          
     LastViewController *lastViewController = [[LastViewController alloc]
                         initWithNibName:@"LastViewController" bundle:nil];
```

i dont understand why this doesnt work?

Comment: What exactly does not work? To find a problem you can try to split large expression in if condition to small chunks to see what part of it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd firstly test to see if your code

```
if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath].textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Ath 1"])
```

actually works. I'd say this is your first hurdle.

Once you can confirm that it is going onto the next stage, creating your view controller, you can start debugging that. I'd put an NSLog above where you create your lastViewController and check to see if your if statement works.

Comment: okay, what code do you have after

    LastViewController *lastViewController = [[LastViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"LastViewController" bundle:nil];

You have allocated and initialized the viewcontroller, but are your presentingit as a modal controller? are you pushing it in a navigation controller?